# What should be the ratio of sidebar navigation to screen in ios?

Tags: navigation, ios, mobile-application, sidebar, navigation-drawer

I am working on designing a native iOS app. For one of the screen need to design a side navigation bar. Android navigation bar standard size details are available here - https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#

I am not able to find similar kind of guidelines for iOS navigation bar. Can someone please provide any references?

Answer (score 1):

I found it tempting to search just because I surprised why I didn't ran into the samples with the sidebar navigation mostly on iOS. After I reviewed a bit, I assume that is probably (the idea behind it described below besides this) because Apple even makes the explanation of [**Navigation Bars**](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/navigation-bars/) covering landscape only.

That made me think of the possible known proportions of their own manifactured product is relatively more appropriate for the landscape navigation instead of portrait design naturally.

> **What Might Be The Purpose Of This?**

As you might notice from the design guidelines like [iOS 10 Design Guidelines for iPhone and iPad](https://v1.designcode.io/iosdesign-guidelines), since the screen width is smaller than the vertical space, it's more likely that one can ran into more samples for the portrait navigation I suppose. Or simply navigation sidebars with the feature **`slide-in / slide-out`**.

> **A Bit Research on The Issue**

I wanted to share beneficial extra links which I ran into when looking for further explanations and hope one can take advantage of,

[Are navigations fading into sidebars?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36464/are-navigationbars-fading-into-sidebars?rq=1)

[Adapting UI to iOS 7: The Side Menu](https://uxmag.com/articles/adapting-ui-to-ios-7-the-side-menu)

[Creating a Sidebar Menu Using SWRevealViewController in Swift](https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/)

[How To Add a Slide-out Sidebar Menu in Your Apps](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)

As a result I found out that sidebar navigation libraries for iOS not exist but mostly deprecated or simply not many source or components described on the [iOS's resources](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=sidebar) itself. Hence there are components for macOS.

> **And the answer is?**

I found the answer after a short review on a **[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175982/how-to-show-resized-sidebar-using-swrevealviewcontroller)** and here another **[covering tutorial](http://sharpcoders.org/post/Sidebar-Navigation-A-Xamarin-iOS-Component)** not with the same topic and it might be a bit harder to find if you're not a coder. Even the **UIViewController's** subclass [SWRevealViewController](http://SWRevealViewController) reveals it, it might be changed as you wish as mobile development turn into platform independent structure with a lot of different involvements.

**P.S.:** I ran into more examples slide-in/slide-out sidebar navigations that mostly covers the %90 of the screen (just letting a bit of the ex-action screen reenable by the user) so that might be a spare idea to further evaluate. And **there is no guideline that I found saying the navigation sidebar's exact size**.

## **TLDR; 260.0f or 220 (not fixed)**